# Trigger GC for DOM element that is not in document

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using idiomatic code to trigger download without server side processing:

```
function toMimeDataTextCsv(str) {
  return 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(str);
}
function createLink(href, fname) {
  var aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.download = fname;
  aTag.href = href;
  return aTag;
}
function triggerDownload(aTag) {
  aTag.click()
}

let csvUri = toMimeDataTextCsv(toCsv(data, ",", "\n"));
let aTag = createLink(csvUri, fname);
triggerDownload(aTag);
```

So there is an object created with `document.createElement` and I can fire an event for it without attaching to the actual document (asynchronously).

- In which scope does that element live?
- Should I dispose it via some API to prevent memory leak?
- Should I only detach all event for this element to make it elegable for GS (above code doesn't show that case)?
- Is it OK to work with detached elements?